# Error: Form1 is a type of windowsApplication cannot be used as an expression

Tags: vb.net, forms

How to solve error when passing and returning some data across the form in visual basic.

> Error: Form1 is a type of windowsApplication cannot be used as an
>   expression
>   showin error on "Form 1" (Public Class Form1)

FORM 1 CODE

```
Public Class Form1
Dim eid As String = ""
Public Sub New(ByVal empid As String)
    InitializeComponent()
    eid = empid
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Declare a variable of string type
    Dim pass As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim frm As New Form2(pass)
    frm.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label2.Text = eid.ToString()
End Sub
End Class
```

FORM 2 CODE

```
Public Class Form2

Dim eid As String = ""
Public Sub New(ByVal empid As String)
    InitializeComponent()
    eid = empid
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Label1.Text = eid.ToString()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim value As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim fr As New Form1(value)
    fr.ShowDialog()

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: on Form1 (Public class Form1)

Comment: That is because Form1 is also your startup form.  It does not know what value of *empid* to pass when your program starts up and Form1 gets created.  You must pick a different startup form or add the default constructor Public Sub New() (without any arguments).

Answer (score 1):

To solve your error message add this to your Form1 Class

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub
```

If you are trying to pass values between forms, you might find this link useful...

http://grantwinney.com/passing-data-between-two-forms-in-winforms/

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1
Dim eid As String = ""
Public Sub New(ByVal empid As String)
    InitializeComponent()
    eid = empid
End Sub
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub
```

```
startup form isn't being called with any parameters
```

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Declare a variable of string type
    Dim pass As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim frm As New Form2(pass)
    frm.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label2.Text = eid.ToString()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you change the project type from class library to windows forms in visual studio.

Head to Application.Designer.vb in your project and there you'll find something like this:

```
Namespace My
    
    'NOTE: This file is auto-generated; do not modify it directly.  To make changes,
    ' or if you encounter build errors in this file, go to the Project Designer
    ' (go to Project Properties or double-click the My Project node in
    ' Solution Explorer), and make changes on the Application tab.
    '
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        
        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
            Me.IsSingleInstance = false
            Me.EnableVisualStyles = true
            Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = true
            Me.ShutDownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses
        End Sub
        
        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.AeonLabs.Layouts.Main.mainAppLayoutForm
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

in the sub OnCreateMainForm() where it has OnCreateMainForm change it to something like this

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
        Me.MainForm = New Global.AeonLabs.Layouts.Main.mainAppLayoutForm
    End Sub
```

and you'll be good to go!!